# Why shouldn't I choose my boundary limits corresponding to the direction I'm integrating?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, mathematical-physics

I have a question regarding the choice of boundary limits when it comes to vector integrals. Why shouldn't I always choose the boundary limits corresponding to the direction I'm integrating. I.e why shouldn't my lower limit be the starting point I'm integrating from? Here is an example:

[image]

I need to calculate the B-field at point P.
When trying to calculate the B-field from the 3rd segment, I get confused over the boundary limits.

The correct solution is:
$$\vec{B}(r)=\int_{0}^{\theta a} \frac{\mu_{0}}{4 \pi} \frac{I d \vec{L} \times \hat{r}}{a^{2}}=\int_{0}^{\theta a} \frac{\mu_{0} I}{4 \pi a^{2}} d L(-1) \hat{k}=-\frac{\mu_{0} I}{4 \pi a} \theta \hat{k}$$
Which indeed gives us an magnetic field in the negative $z$-direction as expected. 
But why shouldn't I integrate from $\theta a$ to $0$ along my $dL$-vector, which is the way I'm integrating? That would result in a B-field in the positive z-direction.

---

I've experienced the same situation in other examples explained here, which does not include angles, but is simple line integrals: [Direction of integration and boundary limits in electromagnetism?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/486273/direction-of-integration-and-boundary-limits-in-electromagnetism)

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/486273/2451